# DocuSign - testing of sending signature request via email

Tags: docusignapi

Our company provides a web application used by hundreds of end users / businesses. We wish to implement DocuSign features into our software. Initially we'll provide the option for our users to request an electronic signature via email.

We've successfully integrated code snippets into our application, but we want to test the integration from the viewpoint of our clients. To do this I set up a trial, end-user DocuSign account in addition to our developer account. When I use the username and password of the secondary, end-user account the attempt to send document for signing falls over in a heap. I suspect this is because the Integrator Key created in our developer account is in a status of Demo. My question therefore is how do we test the integration from the perspective of a client rather than from that of the developer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you log into the trial account via www.docusign.net? If so, then the trial account is on the production servers and your Integration Key (on the developer sandbox system (demo.docusign.net)) is not (yet) valid.

I suggest that you go through the Go-Live process to have your Integration Key promoted to the production systems. There is no charge for the Go-Live process.

(Note that you'll need a minimal paid production account to be used to manage the production Integration Key. If you're in the DocuSign partner program (no charge) then they can give you a free, minimal account for managing the production integration key.)

Once your Integration Key is available on the production systems, you can sign up for a trial account to see what your application integration experience will be like for your customers.